Accesibility Activation point in swift
I have a button, created using ViewBuilder. The button functionality is working using voice over in Xcode simulator. But functionality is not working in Real device. I am using Accesibility Activation point . But getting compiler error. Can anyone help to resolve the issue?
 @ViewBuilder func createButton() -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
            
        })
        .frame(height: 35)
        .accessibilityElement()
        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
        .accessibilityActivationPoint(self.convert(button.center, to: UIApplication.shared.windows.first)
        .onTapGesture {
            
        }
    }

Functionality should work using voice over.
